# Puppet grouping values of all keys from nested structs

Tags: puppet

I am struggeling with puppet not being able to overwrite variables. I have a class a struct as input parameter, which looks like this:

```
  Hash[ String,
    Struct[
      {
        owner_password              => String,
        allowed_sources             => Array,
      },
    ]
  ] $databases,
```

Then I implement this struct as value:

```
$database::databases = {
  development1 => {
    owner_password  => "development"
    allowed_sources => [ "192.0.2.1/24"]
  }
  development2 => {
    owner_password  => "development"
    allowed_sources => [ "192.0.2.1/24"]
  }
```

Then in my module I implement firewall settings. I need all unique `allowed_sources` from all nested hashes in an array to correctly implement the firewall class. Can anyone help me get this?

I tried:

```
$sources = []
$databases.each | db, settings| { 
  $sources << $settings['allowed_sources']
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as `$sources` stays empty.

I tried some shananigans with lambda functions but that spits out the whole top level struct.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I am struggeling with puppet not being able to overwrite variables.

With respect to the kind of struggle I infer from the question, the basic approaches are

1. Favor a more functional style of programming by nesting function calls or chaining functions together (see below).
2. Store intermediate results in their own variables.

> I need all unique `allowed_sources` from all nested hashes in an array to correctly implement the firewall class.

Do you mean

```
$sources = $database::databases.map |$db| { $db['allowed_sources'] }.flatten.unique
```

?

The built-in [`map`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#map) function applies a lambda to each element of an iterable, and returns an array of the results.

The built-in [`flatten`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#flatten) function constructs a new array from its input array by keeping each scalar element and replacing each element that is itself an array with that array's own elements, recursively.

The built-in [`unique`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#unique) function does what you would probably expect: returns an array of all the unique elements of the input array.

It would of course have been possible to store some or all of the intermediate arrays in their own (separate) variables. In some cases that might lend clarity, but here it seems unnecessary.